# Notepad regex replacement : how to split and replace a result?

Tags: regex, notepad++

"1000"=>"Paris", "1001"=>"NewYork", "1002"=>"**Berne/Lausanne**", "1003"=>"Lille"

what I need to split the result that contains "/", so final result is:

"1000"=>"Paris", "1001"=>"NewYork", **"1002"=>"Berne","1002"=>"Lausanne"**, "1003"=>"Lille"

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use this simple regex.

```
("[^"]+")=>"([^\/"]*)\/([^"]*)"
```

Replace the match with `$1=>"$2", $1=>"$3"`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qZ6sE3/5)

- `[^\/"]*` negated character class which matches any character except `/` or `"` zero or more times.
- `[^"]+` Negated character class which matches any character but not of `"` one or more times.

Comment: Hi. I don't understand well the use of ^. Could you explain me that regular expression ?

Answer (score 1):

```
("[^"]+")=>"(?=[^"]*/)([^/]*)\/([^"]*)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1=>$2", $1=>$3`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qZ6sE3/4

Comment: Hi. I don't understand well the use of ^. Could you explain me that regular expression ?

Comment: @user300675 that is for negation...any character after ^ will not match

Comment: @user300675 which case does not match

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
"([0-9]+)"=>"([^"\/]*)\/([^"\/]*)",
```

with 
`"$1"=>"$2","$1"=>"$3`",

[Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/kI5gQ6/1)